# CKEditor. Получить html выделенного фрагмента текста

Tags: html, select, ckeditor

Как получить html код выделенного текста в ckeditor 4.5.5 ?

Получается получить text, с html проблема, методы описаны в интернете не помогают.
Вот мой код с получением текста.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('skipWord1',{
    init: function(editor){
        var cmd = editor.addCommand('skipWord1', {
            exec:function(editor){
                var select = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
                alert(select);
            }
        });
        cmd.modes = { wysiwyg : 1, source: 1 };
        editor.ui.addButton('skipWord1',{
            label: 'Skip',
            command: 'skipWord1',
        });
    },
    icons:'skipWord1', 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
                console.log(range.startPath().elements[0].$); //Выводит то что нужно
                alert(range.startPath().elements[0].$);// Выводит [ObjectHTML***]
```

В консоли отображается то что нужно но как достучатся до него алертом?